# constructor is not a function error in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

When I run the following code:

```
function eatingFood(food){
  this.food = food;
  return 'I"m eating' + this.food;
}

var apple = new eatingFood("apple");
console.log(apple());
```

I got the following error:

> apple is not a function error.

Why is this?

Comment: `apple` holds a string value which returned by `new eatingFood("apple");` not a function

Comment: You should never return inside a constructor.

Comment: Why do you expect `apple` to be a function? You are calling `eatingFood` with `new`. `new Func()` returns an object. What do you think `new` does? Have you read something about `new`, such as the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)?

Comment: @Rajesh uh? I thought new eatingFood created an instance of eatingFood function?

Comment: @FelixKling Yup you are right. My bad.

Comment: @FelixKling I might be confused but new() created an instance

Comment: what should be the answer then?

Comment: Yes, it creates an object with a particular structure (e.g. it will have a property `food`). That object is not a function though. Why did you think it is?

Comment: @Devalor I have already apologised. Also if you already know `apple` is of type `object`(instance of function), what is the objective of this question?

Comment: What you haven't explained is what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: layout and wording improved

Comment: Reordered text to be more clear on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the current code work, you need to do few things.

1. Remove class-object notation.
2. Return a function.

```js
function eatingFood(food){
  this.food = food;
  return function () {
    return 'I"m eating ' + this.food;
  };
}

var apple = eatingFood("apple");
console.log(apple());
```

If you really intend to create an object, then you can very well use the following format.

```js
function eatingFood(food){
  this.food = food;
  this.toString = function () {
    return 'I"m eating ' + this.food;
  };
}

var apple = new eatingFood("apple");
console.log(apple.toString());
```

Comment: it's a must to do function within function if I want to use new() keyword or aka create an instance?

Comment: @Devalor Think about it: why would need a new instance of `eatingFood`? The closest logical thing would be to create a `Food` constructor instead with `eat` functions.

Comment: you did not used new()

Comment: @AndrewLi Just asking your opinion if my answer makes sense? The updated one.

Comment: ah ok, I think the second one is what I wanted. the first one doesn't make sense in real world use case.

Comment: I found object literal make more sense, I've created 3 patterns: https://paste.ee/p/Bxkio take a look.

Answer (score -1):

By using the `new` keyword, `var apple` will be an object that looks like `{food: 'apple'}`.

And.. well... you can't put two parentheses at the end of a object, since objects aren't functions!

Comment: To be more precise though, `apple` is a *variable*. Of course you can have a variable followed by parenthesis (i.e. a call expression). However, the value the variable resolves to matters, and it's not a function in this case.